# Full text search on JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, full-text-search

I have some field in my database which are string containing JSON in it.
It looks like this:

```
2.0.0-p0 :004 > Event.first.title

      Event Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events`   ORDER BY `events`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
     => "{'fr' => 'res', 'en' => 'asdg'}"
```

I wanna do a full text-search on this column, but a simple

```
Event.where("title LIKE ?", title)
```

does not result in anything. I have tried by adding the language key, but it doesn't work. I'm not really sure how to perform this request (or if it is even possible).

Comment: Have you tried -> Event.where("title like ?", "%#{title}%")

Comment: Is your `title` column serialized as a Hash? `"{'fr' => 'res', 'en' => 'asdg'}"` is not a common value for a title

Comment: @Nishu Oh yeah … that was it. I guess Friday is hard for everybody haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying over from comment as answer:

```
Event.where("title like ?", "%#{title}%")
```